# Shut down a notebook instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am using a couple of notebook instances on Google Cloud as my everyday compute engines. The usual workflow is to iteratively develop my data product using Jupyterlab, and then SSH into the machine once the code is ready to be run (My typical workflow is to run several simulations and hyper parameter tuning experiments). At this point, I usually quit the Jupyterlab interface (File > Quit). After the compute process is over, I typically issue a shutdown command on the SSH instance `sudo shutdown -h now` (sometimes this is the last line in a bash script).

However, I observe that this does not necessary shutdown the instance (I am looking at the cloud console to verify this). The only way to shutdown is to use the [Cloud Console shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/notebooks/shut-down). However, this is inefficient since I would like to have a bash script that runs my simulations and then shuts down the instance once I am done.

Is there a best practice to be followed for shutting down notebook instances post the workload is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your notebook instance from Compute Engine too, so you have actually 3 ways for [stopping your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stopping_an_instance) (From the console, with the gcloud command or calling an API).

I recommend you to add the gcloud stop instance command at the end of your bash script.

> gcloud compute instances stop notebook-instance-test --zone=us-west1-b

Remember to add the zone of the instance at the end of the command (if you don't added it the command will ask for the zone)

I tested this myself in a notebook instance and it worked perfectly.